# npm package for Azure B2C SPA application build in Angular 4 and Typescript

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

Is there a working npm package for Azure B2C SPA application build in Angular 4 and Typescript?

I do see old adal packages are available, but those are not working with Angular 4 application

Answer (score 2):

[Here](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-javascript-angular2.4-spa) is an angular 2 sample that shows you how to integrate MSAL.JS with Azure AD B2C. Currently we don't have an Angular 4 sample

Comment: Thanks Parakh. I am able to run this sample app. But somehow the Google login is not working.It throws the following error:  "400. That’s an error.



Error: redirect_uri_mismatch

The redirect URI in the request, https://login.microsoftonline.com/te..." 
 One more issue is that when pop launched for login and login is succesful, the pop up remains open and site get open in POP itself ?

Comment: though it says its URL mismatch but I double checked the url and its correct only.

Comment: It would be great if you guys can have a npm package for the same so that it can be easily integrated with Angular CLI baked Angular 4 apps. Any plans ?

Comment: The sample uses the MSAL npm package. https://www.npmjs.com/package/msal